# Binary XML file line #54: Error inflating class MainActivity.CanvasView

Tags: java, android, canvas

I'm using this class to draw a CanvasOval by inflating this class from my xml file.

```
public class CanvasView extends View {

int height, width;

public CanvasView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CanvasView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CanvasView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity)getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    height = metrics.heightPixels;
    width = metrics.widthPixels;

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        draw(canvas, paint);
}

public void draw(Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {


}
```

I'm getting the oval as needed when I've created a separate file for this class but when I create this class as a subclass in my MainActivity class, I'm getting error saying

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.shashank.mApp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #54: Binary XML file line #54: Error inflating class com.shashank.mApp.MainActivity.CanvasView
```

Comment: I tried your code and it's working normally, did you post a fully class ?

Comment: you have the error: `Binary XML file line #54` - whats there?

Comment: @pskink 
<com.shashank.mApp.MainActivity.CanvasView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

Comment: @GianhTran Did it work both ways?

Comment: @shashank yes, can you show me the package of `CanvasView` class ? it is top line of this class

Comment: you have `CanvasView` as an inner class of `MainActivity`?

Comment: @pskink Yes. When I had it in a separate file, it worked but when I've it as an inner class of MainActivity, it's not.

Comment: so keep it in separate file,i see no reason of storing it as a inner `Activity` class

Comment: @GianhTran package com.shashank.mApp; when I had it in a separate file.

Comment: and yes - it can be done your way - i found a solution in one minute googling, but as i said before it should be stored in a separate file (not as inner class)

Comment: I will continue my work with a separate file but it's really not working for me when it's an inner class.

Comment: If you want to keep it as a nested class, you'll need to make it `static`.